How to I create a fresh new instance of a service in Angular every time?
For example, one might want to implement something like the Command pattern. Using Injector.get still returns the singleton instance, so that won't work.
Edited to clarify, because the transient providers suggested in the comment and one of the answers is not what I need: It needs to create the new instances ad hoc, during interaction with the application, such as a button click, not when a component is instantiated. The instance may have other angular services injected into it. This is because we are using the command pattern for undo/redo functionality. For example:
@Injectable()
export class MyCommand extends Command{

constructor(private someService: SomeService)
{

}

public execute{
  const value = this.someService.getSomeValue();
  //doSomethingWithValue
}
}


Does this answer your question? angular 2 transient providers instead of singleton

Here is the command class that one would want to instantiate new every time. Note that you will need to create a new editCommandInjector each time otherwise it will return the same instance as before.

@Injectable()
export class EditCommand{
    constructor(private someService: SomeService, private someOtherService: SomeOtherService)
    {
    }
}

On your component (or service) where you want to instantiate the new command instance each time you can do the following:
import { Component, Injector, inject } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-component',
  templateUrl: './my-component.component.html',
})
export class MyComponent{

  private injector = inject(Injector);

  constructor() {
  }

  onSomeButtonClicked(){
       const editCommandInjector = Injector.create({ providers: [EditCommand], parent: this.injector });
       const command = editCommandInjector.get(EditCommand);
   }
}


You can just configure provider for your service class in component decorator like
@component({
...,
providers:[ServiceClass]
})
Or
Do this configuration wherever you are injecting this class
